# Is it possible to access package scoped methods by reflection in Java 9 with Jigsaw?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I have the following code to retrieve the default `URLStreamHandlers` for http and https which works in Java 8 by accessing the static package scoped method `URL.getURLStreamHandler()`:

```
private URLStreamHandler getURLStreamHandler(String protocol) {
    try {
        Method method = URL.class.getDeclaredMethod("getURLStreamHandler", String.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return (URLStreamHandler) method.invoke(null, protocol);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warning("could not access URL.getUrlStreamHandler");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Will this still be possible in Java 9 with [jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) or will modifying the visibility in this way be prohibited?

Comment: The possibility to access them via access override may exist, but since package-private methods are not part of the official API, there is no guaranty that the method will exist at all…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It used to be possible in an early prototype but it is no longer. Jigsaw's accessibility rules now restrict access to `public` elements (types, methods, fields) only.

In your example the call to `method.setAccessible(true)` will fail with a message similar to this one:

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make getURLStreamHandler accessible: module java.... does not "opens java...." to unnamed module @1941a8ff

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41265266/2525313) for how to work around that.