# How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?

Tags: java, reflection, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

This exception occurs in a wide variety of scenarios when running an application on Java 9.
Certain libraries and frameworks (Spring, Hibernate, JAXB) are particularly prone to it.
Here's an example from Javassist:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1941a8ff
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.throwInaccessibleObjectException(Reflection.java:427)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:201)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:192)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:186)
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:102)
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass2(FactoryHelper.java:180)
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:163)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:501)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:486)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:422)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:394)
```

The message says:

> Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1941a8ff

What can be done to avoid the exception and have the program run successfully?

Answer (score 297, accepted):

The exception is caused by the [Java Platform Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms) that was introduced in Java 9, particularly its implementation of strong encapsulation.
It only allows [access](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#accessibility) under certain conditions, the most prominent ones are:

- the type has to be public
- the owning package has to be exported

The same limitations are true for reflection, which the code causing the exception tried to use.
More precisely the exception is caused by a call to [`setAccessible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-boolean-).
This can be seen in the stack trace above, where the corresponding lines in `javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions` look as follows:

```
static void setAccessible(final AccessibleObject ao,
                          final boolean accessible) {
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
        ao.setAccessible(accessible); // <~ Dragons
    else {
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
            public Object run() {
                ao.setAccessible(accessible);  // <~ moar Dragons
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To make sure the program runs successfully the module system must be convinced to allow access to the element on which `setAccessible` was called.
All information required for that is contained in the exception message but there are [a number of mechanisms](https://www.sitepoint.com/reflection-vs-encapsulation-in-the-java-module-system/) to achieve this.
Which is the best one depends on the exact scenario that caused it.

> Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}

By far the most prominent scenarios are the following two:

1. A library or framework uses reflection to call into a JDK module.
   In this scenario:

   - `{A}` is a Java module (prefixed with `java.` or `jdk.`)
   - `{member}` and `{package}` are parts of the Java API
   - `{B}` is a library, framework, or application module; often `unnamed module @...`
2. A reflection-based library/framework like Spring, Hibernate, JAXB, ... reflects over application code to access beans, entities,...
   In this scenario:

   - `{A}` is an application module
   - `{member}` and `{package}` are part of the application code
   - `{B}` is either a framework module or `unnamed module @...`

Note that some libraries (JAXB, for example) can fail on both accounts so have a close look at what scenario you're in!
The one in the question is case 1.

### 1. Reflective Call Into JDK

The JDK modules are immutable for application developers so we can not change their properties.
This leaves only one possible solution: [command line flags](https://www.sitepoint.com/reflection-vs-encapsulation-in-the-java-module-system/#commandlineescapehatches).
With them it is possible to open specific packages up for reflection.

So in a case like above (shortened)...

> Unable to make java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1941a8ff

... the correct fix is to launch the JVM as follows:

```
# --add-opens has the following syntax: {A}/{package}={B}
java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

If the reflecting code is in a named module, `ALL-UNNAMED` can be replaced by its name.

Note that it can sometimes be hard to find a way to apply this flag to the JVM that will actually execute the reflecting code.
This can be particularly tough if the code in question is part of the project's build process and is executed in a JVM that the build tool spawned.

If there are too many flags to be added, you might consider using the [encapsulation kill switch](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2017-March/011763.html) `--permit-illegal-access` instead. It will allow all code on the class path to reflect overall named modules. Note that this flag  **will only work in Java 9**!

### 2. Reflection Over Application Code

In this scenario, it is likely that you can edit the module that reflection is used to break into.
(If not, you're effectively in case 1.) That means that command-line flags are not necessary and instead module `{A}`'s descriptor can be used to open up its internals.
There are a variety of choices:

- export the package with `exports {package}`, which makes it available at compile and run time to all code
- export the package to the accessing module with `exports {package} to {B}`, which makes it available at compile and run time but only to `{B}`
- open the package with `opens {package}`, which makes it available at run time (with or without reflection) to all code
- open the package to the accessing module with `opens {package} to {B}`, which makes it available at run time (with or without reflection) but only to `{B}`
- open the entire module with `open module {A} { ... }`, which makes all its packages available at run time (with or without reflection) to all code

See [this post](https://blog.codefx.org/java/reflection-vs-encapsulation/) for a more detailed discussion and comparison of these approaches.

Comment: Is `Lombok` in case 1 and hard to find a way to apply this flag to the JVM that will actually execute the reflecting code because it is part of the project's build process?

Comment: Yes, Lombok is case 1. The question how hard it is to apply the flags belongs [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41520511/2525313).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For [my very similar case](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/701#issuecomment-274295557) it [still fails](https://travis-ci.org/graphhopper/graphhopper/jobs/194113790) even with [that `--add-opens` option](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/commit/d43559a9f90cf72101e4f11c73c61a76c0dc9436). Strange.

Comment: At first glance, the problem might be that you configure the Surefire plugin but the failure is produced by [the failsafe-plugin](https://travis-ci.org/graphhopper/graphhopper/jobs/194113790#L1077). If I am wrong, please ask a separate question.

Comment: @Nicolai I think you should update your answer because JDK 9 now allows illegal access by default and `--permit-illegal-access` will change to `--illegal-access`: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2017-May/012673.html

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I'm waiting for the first EA build that exposes that behavior before updating the answer.

Comment: `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"` worked for OpenJDK 9 because of https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173128

Comment: Could you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918134/jpms-add-opens-doesnt-help-for-java-lang-reflect-inaccessibleobjectexception

Comment: @Nicolai Parlog Can you please tell what canges to make in the modul-info.java file my error is like so: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make boolean java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible0(boolean) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.reflect" to module com.jfoenix                                                               ; with Context to the 2nd solution

Comment: Along with this, for gradle this link was useful for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65225327

Comment: Thanks @NicolaiParlog - setting an environment variable with `--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` worked. But in my case I'm running Jenkins inside a docker container, and Jenkins uses maven to start springboot (many layers!). So setting `ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"` in the Dockerfile passes that option through to springboot. The Java documentation on this environment variable describes the situation nicely - " the command line is not readily accessible to start the application with necessary command-line options".

Answer (score 37):

Just a recent feedback

Many proposals to solve this issue have to do with the vm launcher option `--illegal-access`.

According to Oracle, with [JEP 403 (link1)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403) and [JEP 403 (link2)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8263547) which has been decided to be **delivered from JDK 17 and onwards** , the launcher option `--illegal-access` will stop working!

> Summary Strongly encapsulate all internal elements of the JDK, except
> for critical internal APIs such as sun.misc.Unsafe. It will no longer
> be possible to relax the strong encapsulation of internal elements via
> a single command-line option, as was possible in JDK 9 through JDK 16.

And

> With this change, it **will no longer be possible for end users to use
> the --illegal-access option** to enable access to internal elements of
> the JDK. (A list of the packages affected is available here.) The
> sun.misc and sun.reflect packages will still be exported by the
> jdk.unsupported module, and will still be open so that code can access
> their non-public elements via reflection. No other JDK packages will
> be open in this way.
>
> It will still be possible to use the **--add-opens**
> command-line option, or the Add-Opens
> JAR-file manifest attribute, to open specific packages.

So the following solution will keep working

```
# --add-opens has the following syntax: {A}/{package}={B}
java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

But the solution with `--illegal-access` will stop working from `JDK 17` and onwards.

Comment: This is what helped me in case I was using gson via shazamcrest. I can hardly live without shazamcrest in some cases so I had to use this workaround during testing. To add it to surefire you can do:
<configuration>
    <!-- The add-opens are for shazamcrest that uses gson for random classes -->
    <argLine>
        --add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED
        --add-opens java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED
        --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
        --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
    </argLine>
</configuration>

Answer (score 25):

It is still possible to try with older JKD version.

For Eclipse you need to do 2 things. Go to

1. **Window -> Preference -> java -> Compiler**
   Set Compiler Compliance Level to Specific version
   In my case, Eclipse version was set to JDK 16 I reverted it to 1.8 as my code was written in 1.8
2. **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.**
   Add the JRE installation path (*Select Standard VM*)

It worked smoothly for me..

Comment: Also works for IntelliJ, you need to set up the correct project SDK in  File -> Project Structure window

Answer (score 10):

Using `--add-opens` should be considered a workaround.

The **right thing** is for Spring, Hibernate, and other libraries performing illegal access to fix their issues.

Comment: It'd be helpful to know how you suggest to "fix their issues". Is it by means of method or var handles? IMHO accessing state by reading/writing private fields isn't inherently bad, e.g. it's something explicitely foreseen by the JPA spec.

Comment: For the specific example, it looks like Hibernate or Spring using Javassist to hack into a non-public defineClass method. The Lookup.defineClass method was specifically added to help libraries inject classes so that it is the way forward for that use-case. For the case where JPA and other libraries that need to access private members of their consumers then they will need to document that the consumer opens the package to the library (for annotation based frameworks (like JPA) then that is potentially checkable at build time).

Answer (score 10):

After Java modularization, some jdk internal classes cannot be accessed, so they will report errors directly. So, you need to add below option in VM config when executing the Java program:

For Intellij users follow steps: **edit run/debug configuration -> add the below option in VM options:**

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

This link might be helpful: [upgrading to Java 17](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000040985737/en)

Answer (score 7):

This is a very challenging problem to solve; and as noted by others, the --add-opens option is only a workaround. The urgency to resolve the underlying issues will only grow once Java 9 becomes publicly available.

I found myself on this page after receiving this exact Javassist error while testing my Hibernate-based application on Java 9. And since I aim to support Java 7, 8, and 9 on multiple platforms, I struggled to find the best solution. (Note that Java 7 and 8 JVMs will abort immediately when they see an unrecognized "--add-opens" argument on the command line; so this can't be solved with static changes to batch files, scripts, or shortcuts.)

It would be nice to receive official guidance from the authors of mainstream libraries (such as Spring and Hibernate), but with 100 days to go until the currently projected release of Java 9, that advice still seems hard to find.

After much experimentation and testing, I was relieved to find a solution for Hibernate:

1. Use Hibernate 5.0.0 or higher (earlier versions won't work), and
2. Request **build-time bytecode enhancement** (using the Gradle, Maven, or Ant plugins).

This avoids the need for Hibernate to perform Javassist-based class modifications at runtime, eliminating the stack trace shown in the original post.

**HOWEVER**, you should thoroughly test your application afterward. The bytecode changes applied by Hibernate at build-time appear to differ from the ones applied at runtime, causing slightly different application behavior. Unit tests in my app that have succeeded for years suddenly failed when I enabled build-time bytecode enhancement. (I had to chase down new LazyInitializationExceptions and other problems.) And the behavior seems to vary from one version of Hibernate to another. Proceed with caution.

Answer (score 7):

Add --illegal-access=warn and --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED to your eclipse.ini

Comment: Instructions unclear. I don't use Eclipse, and I still get this error

Answer (score 7):

Add to your JVM command line or go to `eclipse.ini` file in Eclipse Directory and add the following:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Pre Java 17 (because Java 17 removed this parameter) you would also add:

```
--illegal-access=warn
```

Comment: [The `--illegal-access` VM parameter has been removed as of Java 17.](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403#Description)

Comment: this will work in java 8

Comment: With java 8: `java --illegal-access=warn --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED Foo` -> `Unrecognized option: --illegal-access=warn`, `Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.`, `Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue in 2021 while using openJDK 1.8 and STS 4.

```
Window => Preferences => Java => Installed JREs.
```

I added a new JRE (mentioned below) using the add option , browsed to the openJdk folder, select OK. Make the new JDK default. Click on apply and close.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

It worked like a charm:)

Answer (score 3):

I had warnings with hibernate 5.

```
Illegal reflective access by javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions
```

I added latest javassist library to dependencies gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.22.0-GA'
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

In 2021, the issue only appeared when I used OpenJDK language version 16. It worked when I downgraded to a lower version. I am guessing this is because OpenJDK made this: [JEP 396: Strongly Encapsulate JDK Internals by Default](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/396)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue after importing an existing Springboot project based on JDK1.8 into SpringTestSuite4. When I started the application on an embedded Tomcat server, I got this error

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make
> protected final java.lang.Class
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
> throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does
> not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @140c9f39 %09

I added the pre-installed JDK1.8 JRE from my PC to SpringTestSuite4 in the Installed JRE section under Window -> Preferences -> Java and made the added JRE the default. Then I clicked on Apply and then Close.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue while running SornarQube and I got the workaround to upload the sonar report by doing following:

Existing package: Java 16.0.2, MacOS (BigSur)

- Installed sonar_scanner
- Ran this command: export SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="--illegal-access=permit"

Hope this will help to someone if facing the same issue, s/he can try for this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time today trying to get around adding the --add-opens JVM option.  Upgrading to SpringBoot 2.6.4 (which if you're using dependency management, will upgrade to spring framework 5.3.16) fixed the issue without adding the JVM option.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71330846/14396065

Answer (score 1):

I used above suggestion for `--add-opens` in my environment, but at the time of building the code in a pipeline the problem was happening once again. It's important to mention I was using Maven (cucumber as well), and I was leveraging the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, in the end the following configuration allowed the pipeline `build` execution:

```java
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS>--add-opens java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED</JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Env details:

- Java: 17
- Maven: 3.9.5
- OS: Windows and Linux

Answer (score 0):

[How to tell eclipse to add-exports when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068992/how-to-tell-eclipse-to-add-exports-when-compiling?fbclid=IwAR1NF9SKWMkcPsKU3p2TzV9QrEb91SjZ1vTNmqmgBcyw8zZfutk-0pjAqec)

I followed the steps from the top comment but in `Add-exports configuration` pop-up window, I input the modules that were in my error and selected `opens` checkbox instead of `exports` checkbox and saved it. This fixed my problem.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be asking about Eclipse. Ideally, you dont rely on an IDE to compile your code. Use Maven/Gradle for more portable solutions

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. One of the Reason might be using wrong JDK / Project SDK.

To Resolve this issue in Intellij:

> Right Click on the Maven Project -> Open Module Settings -> Project
> Settings -> Project -> Select your SDK to already installed JDK 1.8

It worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse:

```
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs
```

In the wizard that open click on Add, select `Standard VM` and click `Next`, and then Browse to the path of your installed Java in program files. Eg, for me it was `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301\lib`.

Click on Finish then select the newly added JR.

```
Right-click on your Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
```

In the wizard that opens go to the `Libraries` tab and click on `Add Library` then select `JRE System Library` click next. Select `Alternate JRE` and then select the JRE your added earlier from the drop down. Click on Finish.
Go to the `Order and Export` tab and select your added JRE and move it above the other System library that was causing the problem. Select apply and close. You're done.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: only for legacy situations, do not use in any other case.**

I bumped into this problem during testing. I'm using shazamcrest in combination with jMock. This is very handy but shazamcrest is using gson which in turn uses some approach to compare objects that cases this error.

I added the earlier already suggestion solution to my Maven pom.xml in the surefire plugin configuration like this:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- The add-opens are for shazamcrest that uses gson for random classes -->
    <argLine>
        --add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED
        --add-opens java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED
        --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
        --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
    </argLine>
</configuration>
```

This solved the problem.

The only problem left was that running these tests inside Eclipse still poses a challenge. For this I had the add the same settings in the "Run configuration" in the JVM arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting LinkedHashMap.accessOrder not accessible in java 11 reflection.
Tried many things, the only solution that worked is to put this in the servlet class:

```
static {
    try {
        Field field = LinkedHashMap_CustomFieldSerializer.class.getDeclaredField("reflectionHasFailed");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        ((AtomicBoolean)field.get(null)).set(true);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For me i just changed spring-boot-starter-web version and worked for me

Comment: Changed **from** what version **to** what version?

Answer (score -1):

you can use `Unsafe` to bypass, for example

```java
import sun.misc.Unsafe;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class Scratch {

  private static Unsafe reflectGetUnsafe() {
    try {
      Field field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      return (Unsafe) field.get(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

    public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception {
      Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks");
      Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("hooks");
      // this method can not be used in Java 9+ with java modules
      // Unable to make field private static java.util.IdentityHashMap java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.hooks accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @452b3a41
      // field.setAccessible(true);

      Unsafe safe = reflectGetUnsafe();
      Object m = safe.getObject(clazz, safe.staticFieldOffset(field));
      System.out.println(m.getClass().toString());
    }
}
```

Reference: https://xz.aliyun.com/t/10075

Answer (score -2):

exporting the java version solved this issue for me

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.11)
```

Comment: Unclear which of these you set. Sounds like you downgraded from 11 to 8? That will delay the problem, until you later decide to upgrade Java, not fix it.