# Is jol a little broken under Java9?

Tags: java, java-9, jol

Using java-9 build **9-ea+149**  and jol **0.6**.

Running this simple code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(12);

System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseInstance(list).toPrintable());
```

Output:

```
  OFFSET  SIZE     TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
  0     4          (object header)                01 00 00 00 (00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000) (1)
  4     4          (object header)                00 00 00 00 (00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000) (0)
  8     4          (object header)                0e 8d 00 f8 (00001110 10001101 00000000 11111000) (-134181618)
 12     4      int AbstractList.modCount          (access denied)
 16     4      int ArrayList.size                 (access denied)
 20     4 Object[] ArrayList.elementData          (access denied)
```

This access denied part comes from FieldData.java in the method:

```
public String safeValue(Object object) {
    if (refField != null) {
        try {
            return ObjectUtils.safeToString(refField.get(object));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
            // exception, try again
        }

        try {
            refField.setAccessible(true);
            return ObjectUtils.safeToString(refField.get(object));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "(access denied)";
        }
    } else {
        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

And the actual exception is :

> Unable to make field protected transient int java.util.AbstractList.modCount accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @479d31f3.

I think that this has to do with Unsafe features being locked down. The question is how do I get this to run?

I've looked at properties like :

```
-XaddExports:java.base/sun.security.provider=ALL-UNNAMED
```

But can't really tell what it is supposed to look like.

Comment: As per your assumption; You won't. Java 9 is locking down `Unsafe`, simple as that.

Comment: @Esko it's not unsafe which is failing here but reflection.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m

Comment: @JornVernee much appreciated! indeed found my solution there

Comment: Little broken can be little fixed: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/CODETOOLS-7901884. Should be available in JOL 0.7+.

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solutions was indeed to put the correct argument..

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m)