# Does Project Lombok support Java 9?

Tags: lombok, java-9

I have used Lombok in my project, but my colleague do not agree to use it, and his reason is （from [controversy of lombok documents](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html#controversy)）

> Both of these pieces of Project Lombok make use of non-public APIs to accomplish their sorcery. This means that there is a risk that Project Lombok will be broken with subsequent IDE or JDK releases.

But it's a very old document written in 2010, maybe now it has resolved the problem, so I want to know if Lombok will support Java 9 and does it still use the non-public API:s?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The Lombok project has [an issue tracking Java 9 support](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/985). As of January 9th 2018 and version 1.16.20, Lombok officially supports Java 9. From [the changelog](https://projectlombok.org/changelog):

> - PLATFORM: Better support for jdk9 in the new IntelliJ, Netbeans and for Gradle.
> - BREAKING CHANGE: lombok config key `lombok.addJavaxGeneratedAnnotation` now defaults to `false` instead of true. Oracle broke this annotation with the release of JDK9, necessitating this breaking change.
> - BREAKING CHANGE: lombok config key `lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties` is now deprecated and defaults to `true`, that is, by default lombok no longer automatically generates `@ConstructorProperties` annotations. New config key `lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties` now exists; set it to `true` if you want the old behavior. Oracle more or less broke this annotation with the release of JDK9, necessitating this breaking change.
> - DEVELOPMENT: Compiling lombok on JDK1.9 is now possible.

(At the moment, it is no module, though, so you need to place it on the class path. Thanks [Tos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423614/2525313), which first mentioned this.)

Comment: although this is a very good answer for last january, now that java 9 is out... reading the bug though, looks like soon?

Answer (score 4):

The current status of lombok for Java 9 is tracked here: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/985

As of right now this bug is still open and (apparently) actively being worked on. There is an edge release out there that solves most of the issues so at this point it looks like all you need to do is wait..

Answer (score 3):

The issue appears to be resolved since 9 January 2018: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/985#issuecomment-356135454

Per Lombok version 1.16.20 Java 9 is supported.

Comment: This is an answer and a good one - it provides essential new information. @Tos: Which is why I updated my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the status of lombok for Java 9 is tracked [here](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/985).

For hints on why this is an issue, see [this](http://notatube.blogspot.com/2010/11/project-lombok-trick-explained.html) blog post which explains some of the "tricks"/"hacks"