# module-info.java does not work with lombok in Java 9

Tags: java-9, lombok, java-module, module-info

I faced problem during migration our project to **Java 9.**

After I've updated Java 9, I attempt to run project, I faced with compiler errors :-

```
Error:(6, 1) java: package javax.annotation is not visible 
(package javax.annotation is declared in module java.xml.ws.annotation, which is not in the module graph)
```

but I found the solution how to resolve it. **I added `lombok.config` file.**

Then after adding `module-info.java` file to project compiler is displayed errors again

```
Error:(10, 26) java: variable title not initialized in the default constructor
```

***Project example:***

We have entity `Store`:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Story {
    private final String title;
}
```

in root's package I have *`module-info.java`* with content:

```
module javanine {
    requires lombok;
}
```

and in root's project I have  *lombok.config* file with:

```
lombok.addJavaxGeneratedAnnotation = false
lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true

config.stopBubbling = true
```

and somewhere in the code I call it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Story story = new Story("how as");
    System.out.println(story.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: Hi @nullpointer I even couldn't build project. Error:(10, 26) java: variable title not initialized in the default constructor. 
Finally compiler shows this errors
Error:(8, 23) java: constructor Story in class com.test.model.Story cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

and this 

Error:(10, 26) java: variable title not initialized in the default constructor

Comment: That's what is missing from the question. How do you build the project and what error do you get while building. Maybe add the stacktrace.

Comment: @nullpointer I try to start it in IDE and it's failed. Example of project I provide

Comment: I don't know if lombak has support for JDK 9, there is a lengthy issue tracking it here: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/985

Comment: This might just end up being a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520511/does-project-lombok-support-java-9. Though the problem description has some other aspect remaining as well.

Comment: @Andrey: I agree with nullpointer, it looks like your problems are entirely Lombok based. As Alan and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41521711/2525313) state, have a look at [the Lombok issue for Java 9 support](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/985) for a discussion of how to make it work, particularly [this comment](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/985#issuecomment-337741287).

Answer (score 11):

Just configure your module as following:

```
module moduleName {
    requires static lombok;
}
```

Comment: Some extra explanation for people like me using Lombok with Maven and Java 9+'s module system: You may have gone to the [getting started with Maven](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven) page but you also needed to follow the [javac](https://projectlombok.org/setup/javac) instructions (which is what this answer explains).

Answer (score 4):

I've done some work on fixing lombok-with-JDK9 issues, especially when you actually modularize your code (vs. just compiling java8 style code with the javac from JDK9 which has worked for a while now).

Can you give the latest edge release at https://projectlombok.org/download-edge a spin? Thanks!

Comment: now when I indicate requires lombok; in the modul-info.java file, the code is compiled but I receive the next:  " Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module lombok does not read a module that exports org.mapstruct.ap.spi". And during maven compilation it's     swears at "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project some: Compilation failure"

Comment: https://projectlombok.org/edge-releases does not work at all. Any father hints how to solve an issue with lombok and modules?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that URL from, but it is not a correct URL. Try: https://projectlombok.org/download-edge

Answer (score 3):

You can include the dependency in a provided scope to enable the build, without attaching the artifact to the libraries

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```