# Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible altough Java and gradle version are compatible

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to start an app but I get the error message

```
Execution failed for task ':app:extractDeepLinksDebug'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @5710727a
```

I had a look at the answer here [Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500889/unable-to-make-field-private-final-java-lang-string-java-io-file-path-accessible) but my Java SKD version 19 and grandle 7.6.1 should be compatible according to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html.

Can anyone think about a reason as to why I am getting this error and how to tackle it?

Here is the build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.3.0"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here the gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

**Reminder**: I am still having this problem. Does anyone have a suggestion as to why it occurs and how to tackle it. I'll appreciate every comment.