# Gradle: Unable to make field java.io.File.path accessible

Tags: apk

BUILD APK:

```
The option 'android.useDeprecatedNdk' is deprecated.


Executing tasks: [:app:assembleBarvikhaDebug, :app:assembleBarvikhaDebugUnitTest, :app:assembleBarvikhaDebugAndroidTest] in project C:\santrope-core-client-master\apk

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 656 ms

> Configure project :app
WARNING: The option 'android.useDeprecatedNdk' is deprecated.
The current default is 'false'.
It has been removed from the current version of the Android Gradle plugin.
NdkCompile is no longer supported
Crashlytics could not find NDK build tasks on which to depend. You many need to manually enforce task dependencies for generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileSantropeRelease
Crashlytics could not find NDK build tasks on which to depend. You many need to manually enforce task dependencies for generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileBarvikhaRelease

> Task :app:compileLibs
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ���.
'Compiling lib'

> Task :app:copyLibBarvikha
> Task :app:preBuild
> Task :app:preBarvikhaDebugBuild
> Task :app:compileBarvikhaDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileBarvikhaDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateBarvikhaDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:javaPreCompileBarvikhaDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateBarvikhaDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateBarvikhaDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdBarvikhaDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processBarvikhaDebugGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeBarvikhaDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createBarvikhaDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksBarvikhaDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processBarvikhaDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processBarvikhaDebugManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @195e49d6

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileBarvikhaDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:compileBarvikhaDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, C:\santrope-core-client-master\apk\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\barvikhaDebug\out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@ad15e92) before task ':app:compileBarvikhaDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 34s
11 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 6 up-to-date




> Task :app:processBarvikhaDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processBarvikhaDebugManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @195e49d6

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileBarvikhaDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:compileBarvikhaDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, C:\santrope-core-client-master\apk\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\barvikhaDebug\out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@ad15e92) before task ':app:compileBarvikhaDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 34s
11 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 6 up-to-date




Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @195e49d
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500889/unable-to-make-field-private-final-java-lang-string-java-io-file-path-accessible)