# Flutter * What went wrong:

Tags: java, android, flutter

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @6171e36e
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqMUv.png)

Im new to flutter just learning the basics How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check relate issue.

[Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500889/unable-to-make-field-private-final-java-lang-string-java-io-file-path-accessible/76207178#76207178)

---

Adding the following line in `./android/gradle.properties` file in your project

`org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED`

---

Or downgrading to JDK 11