# Android Studio Build Error Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

```
Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @47d8bae5
```

Error when build, cant build app.

Please help

Gradle 7.2 version

Comment: What Java / JDK version do you use? For gradle 7.2 you can not use Java 21 as it is not supported therefore you have to use Java 17 (the other versions in between are outdated as they are short term versions)..

Comment: This has been asked before, but none of the answers have been accepted though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782975/how-to-fix-the-module-java-base-does-not-opens-java-io-to-unnamed-module or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500889/unable-to-make-field-private-final-java-lang-string-java-io-file-path-accessible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix the ''module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module '' error in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782975/how-to-fix-the-module-java-base-does-not-opens-java-io-to-unnamed-module)