# Can not execute maven wrapper verify goal in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I can not execute ./mvnw verify goal. I get a BUILD FAILURE [Error Image here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7wcn.png)

Any idea why this could be?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42675738/2000323

Comment: If you run Maven goals from the IDE Maven tool window - the JDK IDE uses to run the goals is specified in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | **JRE:**. This is where you can change it.

Comment: @Andrey Yes, the JDK 16 was the one causing issues, I have gone back to 1.8 and all is working fine. I will upgrade to 11 and see. Thanks.