# How to Declare Modules in java 9

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I want to use java 9 modules in my project. I want to put my data and service classes (in package named `com.test.base`) in one module named (Base), and put other things like main class and GUI (in package named `com.test.main`) in another module named (Main).

- How to declare simple module (Base)?
- How to declare module (Main) with dependency of (Base) module?
- I also want to use (Base) module with reflection.
- Assume my root package is `com.test` so what directory structure should I use for these modules?

Comment: Did you **read the documentation**? If so, which part confused you? If not, why not? StackOverflow is not a teaching site.

Answer (score 3):

The [jigsaw quick-start](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) is a nice place to start off with this to help you out. To answer the specific questions:

> How to declare simple module (Base)?

Create a class named `module-info.java` within `com.test.base` directory with the definition as:

```
module base {
     exports com.test.base;
}
```

This exports the `com.test.base` package.

---

> How to declare module (Main) with dependency of (Base) module?

Same as the other module `base` a class named `module-info.java` within `com.test.main` directory with the definition as:

```
module main {
    requires base;
}
```

Makes use of the exported package.

---

> I also want to use (Base) module with reflection.

Depending on yoru usage, if the API os removed or changes as listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F7696E02-A1FB-4D5A-B1F2-89E7007D4096), then you can use the `--add-exports` java option as detailed in the [JEP-261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261)

I would also suggest reading [Nicolai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265267/1746118) to [How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m/41265267#41265267) for a nice explanation over how to make use of reflection in Java-9.

> the correct fix is to launch the JVM as follows:
>
> ```
> --add-opens has the following syntax: {A}/{package}={B} 
> java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
> ```
>
> If the reflecting code is in a named module, ALL-UNNAMED can be replaced by its name.

---

> Assume my root package is com.test so what directory structure should
>   I use for these modules?

Your directory structure should be somewhat like:

```
src/main/java
 - com.test
   - base
     - module-info.java
     - com/test/base/Main.java
   - main
     - module-info.java
     - com/test/main/SimpleClass.java
```

Comment: module main {
    requires com.test.base;
}
should be:
module main {
    requires base;
}
the requires statement needs a module name and not a package.

Comment: @NewJavaPythonDev Indeed, corrected. Thanks for the review. :)