# Exception: Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException java 7 with spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, executioncontext

I am getting below exception when adding a few parameters in ExecutionContext that is needed 
afterJob completion.

```
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=MerchantSettlementReportJob at state=MerchantSettlementReportJob.MerchantSettlementReportJob_processDataStep with exception
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:174)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.UNSAFE accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.misc" to unnamed module @5274acd1
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:176)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:170)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.buildMap(FieldDictionary.java:148)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.fieldOrNull(FieldDictionary.java:113)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m)

Comment: I am using java 7 and passing the variable to spring batch