# Error while setting up jenkins through cmd

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I am trying to integrate jenkins with my maven project. While launching jenkins.war in cmd prompt file using the command

```
java -jar jenkins.war --enable-future-java  --httpPort=8082
```

an error is showing up as follows and my jenkis is not being setup on the local host:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field int java.awt.Color.value accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens java.awt" to unnamed module @7b99409d
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171)
        at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallsPlugin.start(GreenBallsPlugin.java:29)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.startPlugin(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:409)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:398)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:563)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1161)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

additional info:
java version "16.0.1"

I am unable to resolve it, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check out this thread, it looks like it is a problem with Java 9+. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m

Comment: Try w/JDK 8 or 11.nNothing else is supported. [Some context](https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-dev/c/VfRq09Yfloo). Bear in mind, that's to run Jenkins, not for use within your jobs; use whatever you need for that.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question . The issue solved after using java 15.0.2