# Mocking classes in Java by using cglib

Tags: java, mocking, cglib

**I try to mock classes in Java by using the Proxy-Mechanism from the cglib library. Every time I try to invoke my Proxy-Method I catch an ExceptionInInitializerError. Does anybody have a clue how to fix this problem?**

This Method is supposed to be my Mocker:

```
 /**
    * @param class/ object that is getting mocked
    * @return mocked object 
    */

    public static <T> T mock(Class<T> clazz) {


        Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
        enhancer.setSuperclass(clazz);

        
        return (T) enhancer.create();


    }
```

The invocation of the Method:

```
    @Test
    public void mockerTest1()
    {
        List<String> mockObject = mock(ArrayList.class);
```

The Exception I catch:

```
ava.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at de.oth.mocker.Mocker.mock(Mocker.java:27)
    at de.oth.mocker.OthMockerTest.mockerTest1(OthMockerTest.java:13)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6a6824be
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:339)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6a6824be
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265267/2478398

Comment: In particular the part about command line flags: `java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED`