# Unable to make field static final boolean java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-11, spring-rest

I have a Spring Feign client which is sending POJO object to remote endpoint using POST:

```
SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
        obj.setId(insertedTransaction.getId());
        obj.setAmount(wpfRequestDTO.getAmount());
```

DTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleRequestFactory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
    
    private BigDecimal amount;  
}


@FeignClient(name = "remote-service")
public interface NetClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/engine/sale", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    SaleResponseFactory setInitTransaction(SaleRequestFactory saleRequestFactory);
}
```

***Service Controller:***

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/sale", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> sale(@Valid @RequestBody SaleRequestFactory saleRequestFactory) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! My object: " +
                ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(saleRequestFactory, new RecursiveToStringStyle()));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

When I make a request I get:

```
    15:24:03.238 [http-nio-8010-exec-1] DEBUG DispatcherServlet[logResult:1101] - Failed to complete request: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field static final boolean java.math.BigDecimal.$assertionsDisabled accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.math" to unnamed module @2a098129
15:24:03.244 [http-nio-8010-exec-1] ERROR [dispatcherServlet][log:175] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/engine] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field static final boolean java.math.BigDecimal.$assertionsDisabled accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.math" to unnamed module @2a098129] with root cause
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field static final boolean java.math.BigDecimal.$assertionsDisabled accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.math" to unnamed module @2a098129
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:130)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.appendFieldsIn(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:645)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:840)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:313)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:166)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.RecursiveToStringStyle.appendDetail(RecursiveToStringStyle.java:73)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.appendInternal(ToStringStyle.java:579)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.append(ToStringStyle.java:466)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder.append(ToStringBuilder.java:860)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.appendFieldsIn(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:654)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:840)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:313)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:166)
        at org.engine.rest.PaymentController.sale(PaymentController.java:42)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
15:24:03.253 [http-nio-8010-exec-1] DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher[matches:167] - Request '/error' matched by universal pattern '/**'
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m)

Comment: Is it possible to set the access level into java code?

Comment: I think it is only possible using JVM arguments as mentioned in the above question. Because if it would be done via code, then I think it would break the purpose of introducing modularity. Also, you could try updating the apache commons to latest version. Maybe the implementation could have changed to handle such issues.

Comment: You could also raise this as a bug to the commons-lang team to fix the way of accessing objects here via `ReflectionToStringBuilder`.

Comment: I don’t know much about this API as I don’t use it, but from the naming, it looks to me like `RecursiveToStringStyle` precisely requests using reflection to print the internal fields of `BigDecimal` instead of just using its `toString()` method. So replacing this strategy with a non-recursive one should solve the issue. I mean, do you really want to get `intVal = null, scale = 2, precision = 4, stringCache = null, intCompact = 1234` instead of `12.34`?

Comment: As I understand from the stacktrace, Code tries to stringify java.math.BigDecimal's internal fields and It can not. Why do you need to use RecursiveToStringStyle?

If you want to log it then you can simply override ToString and pass it log