# Why can't i select JFXTextfield in scenebuilder and add it

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

**JFTTextArea** and **JFXButton** works but why not the **JFXTextField**?

I have added foenix Library so I have got all the JFXTextField
But i am not able to place JFXTextField in the SceneBuilder !!
[image]

Here I have added the library in the project structure.
[image]

If i forcefully add JFXTextField in the sample.xml in the text mode,
It doesn't show compiler error
But instead shows

```
Unable to make boolean java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible0(boolean) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.reflect" to module com.jfoenix
```

The complete Error looks like:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make boolean java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible0(boolean) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.reflect" to module com.jfoenix
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.adapters.ReflectionHelper.<clinit>(ReflectionHelper.java:48)
    at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTextFieldSkin.<init>(JFXTextFieldSkin.java:59)
    at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField.createDefaultSkin(JFXTextField.java:69)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:897)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9547)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:569)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1747)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1187)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1202)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at Material.Design.Scene.Builder/sample.Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:474)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getLayoutBounds()" because "this.textNode" is null
    at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTextFieldSkin.updateTextPos(JFXTextFieldSkin.java:109)
    at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTextFieldSkin.layoutChildren(JFXTextFieldSkin.java:93)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.layoutChildren(Control.java:601)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1207)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1750)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1187)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1202)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at Material.Design.Scene.Builder/sample.Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:474)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I even Tried with this link [Stack OverFlow: Reflection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m)
But couldn't very well connect :(

My sample.xml goes like so:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.2" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="494.0" layoutY="187.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="74.0" text="Button" />
      <TextField fx:id="textField" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="140.0" />
      <JFXTextField fx:id="textField1" layoutX="433.0" layoutY="140.0" promptText="Type in here">
         <effect>
            <InnerShadow />
         </effect></JFXTextField>
      <JFXTextField />
      <JFXTextArea fx:id="JFXtextArea" layoutX="51.0" prefHeight="116.0" prefWidth="518.0" />
      <TextArea fx:id="textArea" layoutX="51.0" layoutY="245.0" prefHeight="130.0" prefWidth="518.0" />
      <JFXButton fx:id="buutton" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="187.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="99.0" text="Button">
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the AnchorPane to StackPane for example?

Comment: I think [that web page](https://jaxenter.com/netbeans/making-custom-javafx-controls-available-in-the-scene-builder) can provide some information for you

Comment: @Tomino I tried with stackPane even i am getting the same issue

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is to implement your custom component via code directly, not Scene Builder/FXML.

Comment: @Tomino Did that even, Got reflect.long.exception, as i have mentoined in the question

Comment: Can you please show us your code when you implemented it manually via code? I am looking at this exception: "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getLayoutBounds()" because "this.textNode" is null", can you make sure that your textNode is not null?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m   I guess this has the solution but i couldn't connect the dots.

Comment: @Tomino I have put the xml code ..please check the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the latest version of java and I am using the latest version of JFoenix and I am getting the same ***InaccessibleObjectException*** as you. There seems to be a problem on their side, I have just contacted them and we will have to wait until they fix it.
Link to the issue: [Not able to add JFXTextField in Scene Builder 16.0.0 #1205](https://github.com/sshahine/JFoenix/issues/1205)

Answer (score 2):

Please use jfoenix 9.0.1 and not 9.0.10 from marven for any jdk/scenebuilder version. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using SceneBuilder 16.0 and JFoenix 9.0.10. The solution I tried is using an earlier version of SceneBuilder, I downloaded **SceneBuilder 11.0** and it worked.

This bug has not been corrected by JFoenix yet.

Answer (score 0):

downloaded SceneBuilder 15.0.0
and use JFoenix 9.0.10
and use java-sdk-15.0.1
and java jdk 15.0.0 or jdk 15.0.1
and add the following settings in your arguments VM :

> --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=com.jfoenix --add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix
> --add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix --add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix --add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=com.jfoenix --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=com.jfoenix

Comment: You should correctly format the link you provided.