# Error creating bean with name 'orikaMapperFacade' defined in class path resource [net/rakugakibox/spring/boot/orika/OrikaAutoConfiguration.class]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

When I Run My Application getting Bean error 'orikaMapperFacade' & Process finished with exit code 1.

below are logs in Intellij Idea..

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orikaMapperFacade' defined in class path resource [net/rakugakibox/spring/boot/orika/OrikaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFacade]: Factory method 'orikaMapperFacade' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang"

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFacade]: Factory method 'orikaMapperFacade' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module

Can anyone help me please regarding this issue??

Comment: looks like same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265267/175554

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. The project runs when I change the JVM from 16 to 15.The orika documentation supports java up to version 11, but it also works with 15.
If the project is with gradle, it needs to be replaced from gradle 6.8 to gradle 6.7 (wrapper version also needs to be reduced)