# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible: 568

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jbehave

I am trying to test some API's using jbehave. While trying to configure my Jbehave stories i am running into the following error (attached below):
I even tried using `--illegal-access=permit`. I used the command `java -cp out com.example.prederiq.PrederaAiq.StoryConfiguration` (where `com.example.prederiq.PrederaAiq` is my package name and StoryConfiguration is my class name that i want to configure) on my windows command prompt but it threw a classNotFoundException. i even navigated to the folder where my Configuration file is present using cd ubuntu commands and tried to use this command but it still did not work.

[image: Full error]

My StoryConfiguration class:

```
public class StoryConfiguration extends JUnitStories {

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration().useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass())).useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder().withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass())).withDefaultFormats().withFormats(StoryReporterBuilder.Format.CONSOLE, StoryReporterBuilder.Format.HTML));
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(),new PrederaAiqApplicationTests());
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> storyPaths() {
       return Arrays.asList("com/example/prederiq/PrederaAiq/test.story");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m)

Comment: I am finding it very hard to understand and I'm confused on what to do in my case. Can you give me a step to step explanation on how i should go about this if you do not mind please. i am a beginner so i am sorry that you've to bear with me

Comment: https://jbehave.atlassian.net/browse/JBEHAVE-1479 - the issue is fixed, but not released yet

Comment: if i am using the java --add-opens commands, what should my parameters be in this case??

Comment: which approach should i use in my case i am confused. And what parameters should i use for my respective approaches