# Unable to stream with Flink Streaming

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, data-stream

I am new to Flink Streaming framework and I am trying to understand the components and the flow. I am trying to run the basic wordcount example using the DataStream. I am trying to run the code on my IDE. The code runs with no issues when I feed data using the collection as

```
    DataStream<String> text = env.fromElements(
               "To be, or not to be,--that is the question:--",
               "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer",
                "The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune",z
               "Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,"
        );
```

But, it fails everytime when I am trying to read data either from the socket or from a file as below:

```
DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);
or
DataStream<String> text = env.readTextFile("sample_file.txt");
```

For both the socket and textfile, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module
```

Comment: What versions of Java and Flink are you using?

Comment: I suppose you probably have an issue with Java configuration on your machine. What version of Java do you use ? Maybe this could help [how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m)

Comment: I am using the following version of JAVA.

openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19

Comment: That's why it isn't working. Flink only supports Java 8 and Java 11.

Answer (score 4):

Flink currently (as of Flink 1.14) only supports Java 8 and Java 11. Install a suitable JDK and try again.