# spring 5.0.2 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class

Tags: java, spring

```
**** config class****

package com.luv2code.aopdemo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

 @Configuration
 @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
 @ComponentScan("com.luv2code.aopdemo")
 public class AopConfig {

 }
 
**** main class****


enter code here
package com.luv2code.aopdemo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO;

import com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.MembershipDAO;

public class MainDemoApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AopConfig.class);


    AccountDAO theAccountDAO = context.getBean("accountDAO", AccountDAO.class);
    

                    
    context.close();

}
```

}

??, ???? ?:??:?? م org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@64bf3bbf: startup date [Thu Dec 16 18:53:43 EET 2021]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.luv2code.aopdemo.AopConfig
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:416)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:254)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:128)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
at com.luv2code.aopdemo.MainDemoApp.main(MainDemoApp.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:122)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:405)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @17baae6e
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:73)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @17baae6e
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.(ReflectUtils.java:52)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
... 21 more

Comment: answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m