# AssertJ: issue with Assertions.assertThat().usingRecursiveComparison().ignoringFields()

Tags: java, junit, assertj

I'm using assertj-core:3.21.0 and JDK 17

Here is an simple example that fails. This works in JDK 16 and assertj-core:3.19.0.

```
        @AllArgsConstructor
        @Data
        class Test {
            @JsonIgnore
            private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            private String name;
        }

        Assertions.assertThat(Map.of(
            1, new Test("a"),
            2, new Test("b")
        )).usingRecursiveComparison().ignoringFields("objectMapper").isEqualTo(Map.of(
            1, new Test("a"),
            2, new Test("b")
        ));
```

The error I'm getting is
`java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private volatile java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.concurrent.atomic" to unnamed module @48140564`

I found if I remove `private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();` from the class it will work, so looks like `ignoringFields` did not ignore `objectMapper` properly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That probably works pre java 17, see [How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m?rq=1)

I'm raising an issue in AssertJ recursive comparison not to use reflexion to compare AtomicReference.

Done: https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2466