# InaccessibleObjectException when trying to create CGLIB Spring proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, cglib, jep-396

```
Feb 02, 2022 12:58:03 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@71318ec4: startup date [Wed Feb 02 12:58:03 IST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 02, 2022 12:58:03 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Feb 02, 2022 12:58:04 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.vishal.main.DrawingMain.main(DrawingMain.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:473)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:355)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1714)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.createEnhancer(CglibAopProxy.java:232)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:181)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @8519cb4
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @8519cb4
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO. R.G is absolutely right, you ought to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question and not just post an unformatted stack-trace (I formatted it for you, editing your question) without any code which caused it. Your subject line is also completely incomprehensible, I am going to update it. Please understand that thousands of volunteers here are ready to help each other, but it is like always in software development: garbage in, garbage out. So please ask better questions to get better answers.

Comment: I answered your question, so I kindly ask you to pe polite enough to either accept & upvote it or to ask in a comment, if there is anything unclear. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is causing Spring not to be able to load the configuration class when using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299710/what-is-causing-spring-not-to-be-able-to-load-the-configuration-class-when-using)

Answer (score 8):

My first guess is that you want to run an older Spring version on a JRE 16+. Probably that old Spring version depends on an equally dated CGLIB version which uses internal Java APIs now blocked due to [JEP 396](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/396), which was implemented for Java 16. Maybe you can simply upgrade CGLIB and continue to use your old Spring version, maybe you need to upgrade both. Without more detailed information from you, it is hard to say. A minimal example Maven or Gradle project on GitHub, reproducing the problem, would be great.

On a second thought, maybe for now you can get away with adding

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

to your JVM command line. But even if it would work, it would not be a particularly sustainable solution, only a workaround.

Comment: So indeed, [a workaround](https://github.com/tarent/extract-tool/commit/2603db6cca29696a7b24ca28b07b357c99f51154) but this is better than not working at all; tbh I’m surprised it’s this easy (and narrow, unlike to allow all reflective accesses or so).

Comment: Then please be so kind as to accept my answer by clicking the grey check mark, making it green. Thank you.

Comment: I’m not the one who can do that, sadly…

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this today (with JDK 17) by upgrading to SpringBoot 2.6.4 (specifically, you need spring framework 5.3.16, so if you're using spring dependency management plugin, you only need to set the springboot version to 2.6.4).

Seems like something was fixed in spring framework 5.3.16 that resolved the issue without having to add the `--add-opens` JVM option.

For reference, the error for me was happening because I had autowired a Supplier bean (not for Spring cloud function).

Comment: Why not just a comment on my answer which also recommended upgrading CGLIB and/or Spring? Besides, I linked to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71302730/1082681) when voting to close this question as a duplicate, where I am mentioning the exact same Spring version and also a few older ones which also contain more recent CGLIB versions.

Comment: For one, I don't have enough reputation points to comment on other answers.  Also, my answer isn't a piggyback off of yours. Your answer is more theoretical; mine is anecdotal, because I'd just encountered the same issue.