# Spring boot java application failed run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need help. My application won't start. I don't know what to do next.
After run my aplication: mvn spring-boot: run
The application does not start. Details below

```
2022-02-05 17:01:57.416  INFO 21092 --- [  restartedMain] fds.Application                          : Starting Application on LAPTOP-FDROPR5V with PID 21092 (C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.4.24-3\apache2\htdocs\audyt\target\classes started by m_arc in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.4.24-3\apache2\htdocs\audyt)
2022-02-05 17:01:57.416  INFO 21092 --- [  restartedMain] fds.Application                          : The following profiles are active: prod
2022-02-05 17:01:57.485  INFO 21092 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@79133b36: startup date [Sat Feb 05 17:01:57 CET 2022]; root of context hierarchy
2022-02-05 17:01:59.197 ERROR 21092 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: fds.Application
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:416) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:254) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at fds.Application.main(Application.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @13c27452
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @13c27452
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 32 common frames omitted

2022-02-05 17:01:59.197  INFO 21092 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@79133b36: startup date [Sat Feb 05 17:01:57 CET 2022]; root of context hierarchy
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My application file code below:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver sentryExceptionResolver() {
        return new io.sentry.spring.SentryExceptionResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer sentryServletContextInitializer() {
        return new io.sentry.spring.SentryServletContextInitializer();
    }
}
```

My application.properites file code:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/magg?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.mail.host=##
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=##
spring.mail.password=##
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.defaultEncoding=UTF-8

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1000MB
```

Someone knows what I can check, what is wrong? I've been trying to solve the problem for 3 days now and I have no idea

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m

Comment: In particular, you should look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69309920/9425556
Your pom.xml indicates that you are using java 8, while this exception is caused by a change introduced in Java 9 and above.

Comment: @jamesngyz Thanks. I changed my jdk library to java 8, but nothing helped. The same error still occurs. Maybe some more suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you to upgrate your java version to 11 and give it a try. I was able to run your code