# Gerrit Error 500 (Server Error): Internal server error Endpoint: /changes/*~*/revisions/*/files?reviewed

Tags: gerrit, java-17

I followed the instructions on this blog to install Gerrit:

https://blogs.sap.com/2021/06/17/how-to-setup-gerrit-locally-on-windows/

But after I uploaded a change to my local Gerrit site for review, when opening this change, an HTML popup showed up saying:

```
An error occurred
Error 500 (Server Error): Internal server error
Endpoint: /changes/*~*/revisions/*/files?reviewed
DISMISS
```

And the list of changed files was not loaded. Java 17 is installed on the computer. When an error message appeared in the browser, the following entry appeared in the error_log.txt log file:

```
[HTTP GET /changes/inventory~41/revisions/1/files?reviewed (zakharovsergey1000 from [fe80:0:0:0:94c5:da3e:51b:2b5e%6])] ERROR com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet : Error in GET /changes/inventory~41/revisions/1/files?reviewed: InaccessibleObjectException [CONTEXT project="inventory" request="REST /changes/*/revisions/*/files" ]
    java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.util.Collections$EmptyList() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @49c43f4e
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
        at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.UnsafeReflectionAccessor.makeAccessible(UnsafeReflectionAccessor.java:44)
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.newDefaultConstructor(ConstructorConstructor.java:103)
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.get(ConstructorConstructor.java:85)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:54)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:696)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:658)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet.replyJson(RestApiServlet.java:1444)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:653)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:290)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:280)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:184)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.raw.StaticModule$PolyGerritFilter.doFilter(StaticModule.java:391)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.GetUserFilter.doFilter(GetUserFilter.java:92)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RunAsFilter.doFilter(RunAsFilter.java:120)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.SetThreadNameFilter.doFilter(SetThreadNameFilter.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy$1.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:139)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllowRenderInFrameFilter.doFilter(AllowRenderInFrameFilter.java:56)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy$1.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:135)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:141)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestCleanupFilter.doFilter(RequestCleanupFilter.java:60)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestMetricsFilter.doFilter(RequestMetricsFilter.java:92)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:64)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:121)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this stackoverflow answer:

[How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m/41265267#41265267)

add

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

to java command line:

```
java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -jar bin\gerrit.war daemon
```