# Migration to java17 issue : module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module

Tags: java, migration, java-17, java-module

My unit tests fail when I migrate from java8 to java 17.
Here is an example of exceptions I get:

> Unable to make java.io.OptionalDataException(boolean) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module

When I googled, I found that I had to add the "--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED" option as an argument to the JVM.

Here is how I did:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
                <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
                <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

But I still have always the same issue :( any help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m)

Answer (score 8):

For me it worked just to combine the arguments in one statement:

```
<argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You allowed me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76876832/418599 .