# Porting Weblogic T3 RMI client to Java 17

Tags: java, maven, client, weblogic, rmi

I am moving my old **SpringBoot 2 / Java 8** application to the newer **SpringBoot 3 / Java 17**.

My issue is related to the **Weblogic T3 client**. Until now I used the `wlthint3client` artifact coming from a **Weblogic 12.2.1.3** installation (compiled by Java 8) which runs with no issues.

Using the same artifact inside the new architecture, based on **SpringBoot 3 / Java 17** the `new InitialContext(environment)` instruction **stucks forever**!!!

Could anybody tell me if there exist a newer release of the Weblogic Client, or a workaround for that issue?

Here is a fragment of the code which uses the client:

```java
public static MyRemoteEJB lookup(
    String clusterAddress,
    String userName,
    String password
)
    throws NamingException
{
    Properties environment = new Properties();

    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,            clusterAddress);

    if (null != userName) {
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
    }

    if (null != password) {
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    }

    environment.put("weblogic.jndi.allowExternalAppLookup", "true");
    environment.put("weblogic.jndi.relaxVersionLookup",     "true");

    InitialContext context      = new InitialContext(environment);
    String         resourceName = String.format(
        "remote-app#%s",
        MyRemoteEJB.class.getName()
    );

    return (MyRemoteEJB)context.lookup(resourceName);
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you really using Spring Boot 3... than you have to use JDK17 because SB 3 requires JDK 17+ (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.9/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started.system-requirements) ...

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I am using java 17.

Comment: It could be a network issue or a java issue as WebLogic 12.2.1.3 does not support Java 17.
Add following JVM args to set timeouts to your T3 connection : 
-Dweblogic.jndi.connectTimeout=300000
-Dweblogic.jndi.responseReadTimeout=300000

Comment: I debugged the Weblogic T3 Thin Client and I found the exception raised only for Java 17, and I discovered that the bug is known, but I have no access to the Oracle Portal at  https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2928858_1.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a lot of effort, I finally solved the issue!

I am going to describe which the solution is, and how I achieved it.

The first step was to ask to the Oracle support, provided by my company, the **Jakarta** version of the **Weblogic T3 Thin Client** shipped with **Weblogic 14.1.1.0**.

I decompiled and debugged it by the **IntelliJ built-in java decompiler** to get enough information to active and redirect the T3 client debug logs to my console (look at the below source code).

Here the relevant source code:

**logging.properties**

```bash
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=FINE

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

**Main.java**

```java
package org.example;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    private static void loggerSetup() {
        String pwd = System.getenv("PWD");

        System.setProperty(
            "java.util.logging.config.file",
            (pwd + "/src/main/resources/logging.properties")
        );

        System.setProperty("com.bea.core.debug.DebugLegacy.stdout", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.diagnostics.debug.DebugLogger.DISABLED", "false");

        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugAbbrevs", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugAllowList", "true");
        //System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugClassLoadingContextualTrace", "true");
        //System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugClassLoadingVerbose", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugCluster", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugClusterVerbose", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugConnection", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugDGCEnrollment", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugFailOver", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugGenericMethodDescriptor", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugJNDI", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugJVMID", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugLegacy", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugLoadBalancing", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugMessaging", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugRMIRequestPerf", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugRouting", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.DebugStubGeneration", "true");
        System.setProperty("weblogic.debug.ServerHelp", "true");
    }

    private static Object lookup(
        String clusterAddress,
        String userName,
        String password
    )
        throws NamingException
    {
        Properties environment = new Properties();

        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,            clusterAddress);

        if (null != userName) {
            environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
        }

        if (null != password) {
            environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        }

        environment.put("weblogic.jndi.allowExternalAppLookup", "true");
        environment.put("weblogic.jndi.relaxVersionLookup",     "true");

        InitialContext context      = new InitialContext(environment);
        String         resourceName = String.format(
            "remote-app#%s",
            MyRemoteEJB.class.getName()
        );


        return context.lookup(resourceName);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loggerSetup();

        logger.info("Connecting...");

        try {

            Object myRemoterEJB = lookup("t3://127.0.0.1:7002", null, null);

            if (null != sogeiAdapterEJB) {
                logger.info("Remove EJB got!");
            }

        } catch(NamingException e) {
            String message = e.getMessage();

            if (message.contains("MyRemoteEJB")) {
                logger.info("Remote EJB got, but not marshaled.");
            } else {
                logger.severe(message);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Running it I got several exceptions, but only one really **related to my problem**:

```bash
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private static java.lang.ClassLoader java.io.ObjectInputStream.latestUserDefinedLoader() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @50675690
```

The above one was the root cause of:

```bash
Try to create JVM connection 1 time, encounter : java.io.IOException: Timed out while attempting to establish connection to :t3://127.0.0.1:7002
```

The solution was provided by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73292361/418599), so I added the JVM arguments:

```bash
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
```

All the connections issues are gone!!!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Did you manage to integrate that with your maven project? How did you do that?

Comment: Those paramereters must be put on the JVM command line, not in maven.

Comment: Thanks.
After migrating my project to jdk17 and passins those flags to the jvm I am getting the same connection error (with jdk8 works fine the connection)

Comment: Very strange, it works for me and many others. Please, post your command line here...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I was getting the same error. For me adding the following flag helped:

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
```

It's nice to know how to get the logging up and running.