# Exception when i try to convert a java object into an xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring, marshalling

I'm trying to convert a java object into an xml file.

this is the object's class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Employee {

    int eId;
    String eName;
    int eSalary;


    public Employee(){

    }

    public Employee(int eId, String eName, int eSalary) {
        this.eId = eId;
        this.eName = eName;
        this.eSalary = eSalary;
    }


    public int geteId() {
        return eId;
    }

    public void seteId(int eId) {
        this.eId = eId;
    }

    public String geteName() {
        return eName;
    }

    public void seteName(String eName) {
        this.eName = eName;
    }

    public int geteSalary() {
        return eSalary;
    }

    public void seteSalary(int eSalary) {
        this.eSalary = eSalary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "eId=" + eId +
                ", eName=" + eName +
                ", eSalary=" + eSalary +
                '}';
    }
}
```

While this is the class I made to convert the object:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import java.io.File;

public class XMLConverter {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        try {
            // create `Employee` object
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.seteId(101);
            employee.seteName("John Watson");
            employee.seteSalary(30000);

            // create an instance of `JAXBContext`
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);

            // create an instance of `Marshaller`
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

            // enable pretty-print XML output
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            // create XML file
            File file = new File("src//main//resources//employeebean.xml");

            // convert employee object to XML file
            marshaller.marshal(employee, file);

        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

when i run the main method i geth this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:115)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:402)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:94)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:503)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:262)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:249)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:456)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:656)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:599)
    at XMLConverter.main(XMLConverter.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6833ce2c
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:200)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.getMethod(Injector.java:184)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.access$000(Injector.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1.run(Injector.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1.run(Injector.java:165)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.<clinit>(Injector.java:164)
    ... 22 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Tried to search for a solution but still couldn't solve the problem.

Every suggestion is really uppreciated,
thanks in advance

Comment: Try item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265267/2834978)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this annotation on Employee class `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`

Answer (score 0):

Please add these dependencies to your pom.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-ri</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
      <type>pom</type>

  </dependency>
```