# Error running Cucumber tests with Gradle in IntelliJ Error

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd

I got subject error when run cucumber api tests with Gradle via IntelliJ. Same error when runing commandline as well with `gradlew cucumber` ( Below is my edit configurstion:

[image]

Error:

```
    May 12, 2022 7:04:29 PM cucumber.runtime.java.ObjectFactoryLoader loadSingleObjectFactory
WARNING: Loading deprecated ObjectFactory from runtime via reflection: cucumber.runtime.SerenityObjectFactory
May 12, 2022 7:04:29 PM com.google.inject.internal.MessageProcessor visit
INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1753acfe
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
......
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1753acfe
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:258)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:101)

at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)

at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:50)
    ... 8 more

Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:124)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:43)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051)

    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)

... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
```

My related `build.gradle` parts:

```
    sourceSets {
        integrationTest {
            compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
            runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        }
    }
    
    configurations {

        cucumberRuntime {
               extendsFrom testImplementation
         }
        integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
        integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
        integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
    }
    
    task integrationTest(type: Test) {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        description = 'Run integration tests.'
        check.dependsOn(it)
        group = 'verification'
        testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
        classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
        shouldRunAfter test
    }
    
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, testClasses
//    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'xxxx.stepdefinitions', 'src/integrationTest/resources']

        }
    }
}
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        // Prints any test outcomes to the console
        testLogging {
            events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
            showStackTraces true
            showExceptions true
            showCauses true
            exceptionFormat "full"
        }
    }
```

CucumberTest class

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/reports/cucumber-html-report",
        "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
        "json:target/cucumber.json"},
    tags = {"@test"},
    glue = {"com.abc.stepdefinitions"},
    features = "src/integrationTest/resources/features/")
public class MyServiceCucumberTests {
}
```

My Versions:

```
Java 17
Gradle 7.4.2
serenityCucumber   : "1.0.29"
serenity           : "2.0.90"
cucumber           : 4.8.0
IntelliJ Ultimate 2021.1
```

Further it gives same above error in commandline as well (`gradlew cucumber`)

However I have same setup with `Maven` and `Java 11`, it runs fine via both IDE and commandline

Comment: I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69160452 solution assuming that it is Java version related, but no luck

Comment: managed to run tests via IDE using gradle tasks/ io.cucumber.core.cli.Main. Below are the versions

`Java17
Gradle 7.4.2
serenity-cucumber6 - 2.6.0
serenity-rest-assured -  2.6.0 `. However still still caanot run the as a gradle cucumber task (mentioned in the question). when run I get error in `javaexec ` step   - Error: `Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`