# How to fix "java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException"

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'm traying to create a simple Spark Session, that read a csv file. But it show me this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private transient java.lang.String java.net.URI.scheme accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @bcec361
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$getClassInfo$3.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:336)
at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$getClassInfo$3.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:330)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.getClassInfo(SizeEstimator.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.visitSingleObject(SizeEstimator.scala:222)
at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.org$apache$spark$util$SizeEstimator$$estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:201)
at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SharedInMemoryCache$$anon$1.weigh(FileStatusCache.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SharedInMemoryCache$$anon$1.weigh(FileStatusCache.scala:107)
at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.setValue(LocalCache.java:2222)
at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.put(LocalCache.java:2944)
at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.put(LocalCache.java:4212)
at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.put(LocalCache.java:4804)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SharedInMemoryCache$$anon$3.putLeafFiles(FileStatusCache.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$$anonfun$listLeafFiles$2.apply(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:130)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$$anonfun$listLeafFiles$2.apply(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:128)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.refresh0(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.<init>(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$createInMemoryFileIndex(DataSource.scala:533)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:371)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.text(DataFrameReader.scala:714)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.text(DataFrameReader.scala:686)
at org.example.SparkSessionTest$.main(SparkSessionTest.scala:19)
at org.example.SparkSessionTest.main(SparkSessionTest.scala)
```

This is my code :

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SparkSessionTest {

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("SparkByExample")
      .getOrCreate();
    
    println("First SparkContext:")
    println("APP Name :"+spark.sparkContext.appName);
    println("Deploy Mode :"+spark.sparkContext.deployMode);
    println("Master :"+spark.sparkContext.master);

    val df = spark.read.text("src/data/test.txt")

  }
}
```

I'm using :

- jdk-11.0.15.1
- scala 2.12.10
- spark 3.1.3

And im using Intellij IDE and maven

Comment: Same thing with java 8?

Comment: @AminMal yes and i tried with java 18 too

Comment: How do you run this code? From the main class or from some test class?

Comment: @sierikov from the main class

Comment: With JDK 1.8 you should have it work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m reading that helped me to solve the problem by adding add-opens argument

Answer (score 1):

If you are using intelliJ,

- go to file => project structure => Project
- check if you have SDK set to 1.8 else download it.

Comment: How exactly does downgrading the JDK solve the problem?

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: That was a rhetorical question, I think that recommending to downgrade the JDK is not a proper solution.

Comment: in my case i needed to cchange version to 1.8 in run configuration of IntelliJ as well

Comment: @Pukhrajsoni that's great, I did the same thing when I faced the problem and it worked.