# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'. in flutter

Tags: java, flutter, module

I'm trying to run an app in flutter and I got this error. Anyone can help ?

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @7bcea5fe0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just figured out the solution
All I did is to add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
```

to the `gradle.properties` file

See this link : [How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m/41265267#41265267)