# Maven Launch4j Plugin InaccessibleObject // add JVM argument to POM

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin, launch4j

first: Please be gentle, I'm very new to this.

I have a java application which is a client connecting to a wildfly instance. Running this from IDE works. Now i want to wrap the client to an .EXE using akathist-launch4j-maven-plugin and the maven-shade-plugin. I'm using those instead of jpackage since i dont want an installer, but a plain exe to run the programm. The wrapping works and runs until it tries to call java.util.AbstractMap().

Error message:
`Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.util.AbstractMap() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @7e32c033`

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265267/21859971 i gathered it would work if i passed "--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" to the jvm.

The exclusion filters were added because before it would run into problems with the signed jars inside the shaded one.

The questions now are:
a) Is that the right way to go about it?

b) If so, how do I modify the pom to include this argument?

Pom plugins excerpt:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
            </filters>              
            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
            <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
            <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <mainClass>de/cni/client/gui/pages/main/StartApplication</mainClass>                        
                </transformer>
            </transformers>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>                                
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>l4j-clui</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>launch4j</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <headerType>console</headerType>
                    <jar>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-shaded.jar</jar>
                    <outfile>${project.build.directory}/app-client.exe</outfile>
                    <classPath>
                        <mainClass>[..]/client/gui/pages/main/StartApplication</mainClass>
                        <preCp>anything</preCp>
                    </classPath>                                
                  <jre>
                    <path>${java.home}/bin</path>
                    <minVersion>17.0.2</minVersion>
                    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
                    <requiresJdk>true</requiresJdk>
                    <requires64Bit>true</requires64Bit>     
                  </jre>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

**Edit**:
As is tradition, an hour after posting this i tried something i did before and now it worked.
I added:

```
                    <opts>
                        <opt>--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</opt>
                        <opt>--add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED</opt>
                    </opts>
```

to the  of the launch4j plugin and now it is running.

I'm not going to put this as an answer since I'm reasonably sure there is a better (correct) way to solve this.