# In BDD selenium while using webdrivermanager I get "IllegalStateException"

Tags: java

```
public static WebDriver driver;
//@openBrowser

public void openup() {
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().create();
     WebDriver  driver = new EdgeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.ikea.com/ca/en/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
//@clseBrowser
public void close () {
    driver.close();
}
//Constructo
public DriverFactory (){

    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
}
```

The error is:

```
Dec 18, 2023 4:13:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.MessageProcessor visit
INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @783e6358
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.create(ProviderMethod.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.createProviderMethod(ProviderMethodsModule.java:272)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:116)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:100)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:344)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:353)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:137)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at net.thucydides.core.guice.Injectors.getInjector(Injectors.java:27)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.di.WebDriverInjectors.getInjector(WebDriverInjectors.java:10)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity.setupWebDriverFactory(Serenity.java:123)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity.initializeWithNoStepListener(Serenity.java:99)
```

I tried with other browser and check all version. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like some of the code is not ready to be run on Java 11+. Depending on specifics, you may want to either run your tests on Java 8 or upgrade dependencies to their newer versions, and go through a more complete explanation e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265267/1374322).